# jenkins python api install plugin

Tags: python, jenkins

I'm using [python-jenkins](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=plugin#jenkins.Jenkins.install_plugin) library to install plugins on jenkins.
The function `install_plugin` return before having fully installed the plugin. I reboot the jenkins server imediately after that function call.

What should I do to prevent this issue ?

Comment: actually, the function return when the plugin is installed but not when all dependencies are...

Comment: Do you have any error that could explain that early return? Can you add the code used to install dependency?

Answer (score 0):

facing similar issue. Code snippet is as below.

```
import jenkins

server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://192.168.99.100:8080', username='guest', password='guest')
user = server.get_whoami()
version = server.get_version()
print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))

#Get installed plugins
#plugins = server.get_plugins(3)
#print(plugins)

#Download a plugin - Convert to pipeline

info = server.install_plugin('convert-to-pipeline',True) #Convert To Pipeline
print(info)
```

Also, output is empty string from **init**.py instead of True

Jenkins' log have an error of broken pipe